# Render SVG markup using Jasper Reports

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am trying to render bar or line charts using jasper reports framework.Currently I am able to create .png images for the charts that get embedded in the report generated.

However, I now want to render the charts as svg markups so that I can attach hooks to it for client side manipulation using some javascript library like d3.js.How can I generate charts as svg mark-ups using Jasper-Report Framework?

If its not possible to do it using Jasper then is there an alternative through which I can add dynamic behaviour to my server-side rendered reports?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about JasperReports but with [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg) you can create charts in SVG format, including some hooks to enable interaction with JavaScript code.  Not all the renderers in JFreeChart have been updated to support this yet, but the common ones including bar charts are done.

There isn't a lot of documentation written for it yet either, but the approach is basically the same as outlined in this [blog post](http://www.object-refinery.com/blog/blog-20140509.html).  If you look at that first, to understand the approach, then look at the JFreeChart and JFreeSVG sources, I don't think it would be hard to figure out.

Comment: As a note jasper repor uses JFreeChart when generating charts within framework